# В каких случаях нужно ставить нулевой символ в массив/строку?

Tags: c, c++

В принципе ничего сложного с одной стороны, но потом при работе с функция бывает вылазит как раз эта проблема. Как быстро ориентироваться где должна завершатся строка нулевым символом, а где массив или где функция какая-то его не поставила. Есть какие-то методы, которыми вы пользуетесь в этом вопросе для быстрого определения где не хватает его? Ну кроме простых правил, хотя и их можете перечислить, потому что может я забыл их или не так использую. Кстати, слышал, что есть какие-то различия  в этом деле между Си и С++.

Comment: Пример проблемы не приведёте? (Разумеется, кучу ошибочных вариантов я могу придумать и сам, но они не обязательно будут теми, которые интересуют Вас)

Comment: @alexlz, если не сложно, то напишите эти ошибочные варианты. Подойдет все, а то сталкивался часто, а так чтобы вспомнить и правильно описать, не получается.

Comment: @avp strncpy (и пр.) при превышении счётчика?

Comment: @alexlz, не понял, как счетчик может быть превышен?

Из `man strncpy` 

A simple implementation of strncpy() might be:

           char *
           strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)
           {
               size_t i;

               for (i = 0; i < n && src[i] != '\0'; i++)
                   dest[i] = src[i];
               for ( ; i < n; i++)
                   dest[i] = '\0';

               return dest;
           }

Comment: @avp, вероятно подразумевается, что строки не могут быть в такой интерпретации быть длиннее 2^16 символов.

Comment: @gecube, а откуда 2^16? 

Обычно `size_t` это `unsigned long`, соответственно в 32-бит получается 2^32, а в 64-бит 2^64.

Понятно, что это теоретический размер.

Comment: @avp, зависит от типа переменной-счетчика, используемой в ф-циях работы со строками. Могу предположить, что в каких-то библиотеках там вообще unsigned char используется с вытекающим ограничением в 255 символов. Другой вопрос, что вряд ли это есть стандартное поведение этих ф-ций.

Comment: @avp strlen(src) >= n

Comment: @alexlz, Вы имеете в виду не завершающий 0 в `src`, а положить 0 в dst?

Это бывает актуально, можно дописать в свою lib


    // like strncpy(), but allways put nil to dst. Returns addr of end (nil) in dst
    char *strncpyz (char *dst, const char *src, size_t n);

Comment: @avp да это понятно. Просто приходится об этом помнить. Правда цели всех этих strnXXX -- не обеспечение нормальной работы, а предотвращение срыва стека и аналогичных шалостей. 

Но можно найти и другие фокусы, где теряется замыкающий ноль (просто надо вспоминать, а неохота).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В C++ для строк пользуйтесь исключительно `std::string` и его вариантами (`std::wstring` и т. д.). В C строка **должна** завершаться нулевым символом, если где-то его нет — это грубая ошибка, ведущая к чтению неинициализированной памяти и undefined behaviour. Массив, который не является строкой, нельзя использовать как строку, т. к. он имеет право не оканчиваться нулевым символом и содержать нулевые символы посередине.

---

Как правильно отметил [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), разница между массивом и строкой не синтаксическая, а логическая. Вы должны знать, где у вас массивы, а где строки.

Comment: @VladD, смысл тогда от такой конструкции? Чтобы не писать размер, но при этом sizeof делать? Или что-то другое?

Comment: @strol: Да. Если писать вручную, можно случайно ошибиться. Пусть лучше машина работает :-)

---
Кстати< вот хороший обзор по теме: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4810668/276994

Comment: Но в C++ иногда выгоднее использовать нуль-терминированные строки.

Comment: @Janycz: Для интеропа (вызовы WinAPI) иногда приходится, но во всём проекте, особенно _большом_ проекте — не стоит.

Answer (score 6):

[@strol](/users/14769/strol), формально в Си **нет строк**.

Есть только массивы символов.

А строка это *логическое* понятие. Несколько символов (естественно, в массиве) завершающиеся нулем.

Если используете так называемые строковые функции (strcmp, strcpy, puts, printf ("%s...) и т.п.), то передаваемые в них массивы символов (`char *` указатели) **должны** завершаться нулем.

Comment: @avp, А если `char* str = "abcd";`, то это тоже массив? Знаю, что это строковая константа, расположенная в области памяти read only. Но а живет она пока на неё кто-то указывает? И ещё, если это тоже массив, то почему можно объявить так : 

    char str[] = "abc"; //good
    char str[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' }; //good

но нельзя объявить так :

    char* str = "abc"; //good
    char* str = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' }; //error

Comment: @strol: Ой, сорри, моя ошибка. `str[4] = "abc"` — гуд. Удалю свой комментарий.

Comment: @strol: (продолжение) А вот `char* str = "abc";` означает следующее: вы заводите указатель на символ `str`, и инициализируете его _адресом_ строки `"abc"` (то есть фактически тоже последовательности символов `{ 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' }`), которую _компилятор_ за вас где-то аллоцирует и даёт вам её адрес. Видите различие? В первом случае вы сами выделяете память, во втором указываете на чужую память.

---
Поскольку компилятор для второго случая даёт вам read-only-символы, правильно будет использовать `const char*`.

Comment: @VladD, а по каким соображением сделали так, что компилятор выделяет память в read only для `char* str`? Чем бы обратное было чревато? И по чему для `char* str` можно пользоваться простым синтаксисом `"abc"`, но нельзя `{'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}`?

Comment: @strol: это он выделяет память не для `char*`, это для `"abc"`. Почему так сделано? Подумайте, что в противном случае вывел бы такой код:

    char* s = "abc";
    s[0] = 'X';
    printf("abc");

Для выражения `char* str = "abc";` правая часть (`"abc"`) есть **адрес строки**. А `{'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}` — это не массив, это лишь _инициализатор массива_. Откуда несчастный компилятор из _инициализатора_ массива возьмёт _адрес_? Для получения адреса нужен сам массив, а его-то и нету.

Comment: @VladD

    #include <stdio.h>
    char s[] = "Momi";
    int main() {
      printf("%s\n", s);
      s[1] = 'a';
      printf("%s\n", s);
      return 0;
    }

Comment: @alexlz: UB. На разных компиляторах/платформах или просто с другими параметрами компиляции имеет право быть разный результат.

Comment: @VladD, ясно. Спасибо! Кстати, не знал что у "abc" будет 1 адрес в этом коде : 
`
char* s = "abc";
char* s2 = "abc";
printf("%p\n", s);
printf("%p", s2);`
Хотя это логично, учитывая, что иначе компилятор бы не знал к какому адресу обратится. Получается, что "abc" - это static const с глобальной видимостью?

Comment: @VladD, может я не внимательно ваши сообщения читал, но почему 

    `char s[] = "Momi";
    s[1] = 'a';`

  -это UB? Компилятор же должен размер высчитывать правильно. То есть, `char s[] = "Momi";` должно быть эквивалентно `char s[5] = "Momi";` Почему тогда нельзя модифицировать элементы? Нагуглил вот ещё что http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%2B%2B , 

    void MyFunc1( int *arr );    // компилятор посчитает
    void MyFunc2( int arr[] );   // эти три объявления
    void MyFunc3( int arr[15] ); // абсолютно идентичными  

Наверное после таких источников и возникает недопонимание.

Comment: @strol: адрес будет не обязательно один и тот же (это не гарантировано), но большинство компиляторов «соединят» одинаковые строки, чтобы не расходовать память. Если бы символы внутри строковых констант можно было изменять, такая оптимизация была бы невозможна. Так что да, глобальная константа.

Comment: @strol: UB там не из-за размера, а из-за модификации символа, о котором компилятор уверен, что он read-only. Размер автоматически посчитается правильно.

Comment: @VladD пример, когда будет креш и мат будьте добры привести. Аргументы против уже привёл @strol.

Comment: @alexlz: Креш будет, например, на Sparc, где компилятор помещает строковые константы в память, которая аппаратно доступна только для чтения. По поводу мата — длинная история, процитирую вот [это](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213):

> For example, accessing an out of bounds array element is a key part of the canonical stack smashing attack. [...] following the OOB array access your computer will begin executing exploit code, and that code is what will format your disk.

Туда же http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html и следующие 2 статьи.

Comment: @alexlz, а что с Вашим куском кодом непонятно?

sizeof(a) очевидно будет 5 (там где sizeof(a[0]) == 1).

Т.е. это можно расписать так

    #define Momi "Momi" // символьная константа 5 байт вместе с 0, разместить в секции .rodata
    char a[sizeof(Momi)] = Momi; // отвести 5 байт в секции .data  и инициализировать их, пометить в таблице символов именем a и атрибутами global

Comment: @avp непонятно, на какой архитектуре это будет незаконно.

Comment: @alexlz, я про такие не знаю.

Comment: @avp был комментарий @VladD, касающийся моего куска кода.

     @alexlz: UB. На разных компиляторах/платформах или просто с другими параметрами компиляции имеет право быть разный результат, включая креш и мат из динамиков

Я был удивлён.

Comment: Я тоже. 

Хотелось бы конкретный пример, а не ссылку на 3 статьи, где при беглом обзоре рассмотрения подобного случая 

    char a[] = "abc"; // инициализированный глобальный массив
    main () { 
      a[2] = 1; // UB ???
    ... 
    }

я не заметил.

Comment: @alexlz, @avp: Ох, у вас массив, а не указатель. Сорри, провтыкал. UB, конечно, с указателем.

Answer (score 5):

Рискну определить не очень четкое правило: строка (то есть `null terminated array`) это то что можно квалифицировать как *Human Readable*, то есть предназначенное для юзера/человека. В противном случае это просто массив `char`